# Spring Batch or JMS for long running jobs

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-batch

I have the problem that I have to run very long running processes on my Webservice and now I'm looking for a good way to handle the result. The scenario : A user executes such a long running process via UI. Now he gets the message that his request was accepted and that he should return some time later. So there's no need to display him the status of his request or something like this. I'm just looking for a way to handle the result of the long running process properly. Since the processes are external programms, my application server is not aware of them. Therefore I have to wait for these programms to terminate. Of course I don't want to use EJBs for this because then they would block for the time no result is available. Instead I thought of using JMS or Spring Batch. Does anyone ever had the same problem or an advice which solution would be better?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what forms of communication your external programs have available. JMS is a very good approach and immediately available in your app server but might not be the best option if your external program is a long running DB query which dumps the result in a text file...

The main advantage of Spring Batch over "just" using JMS as an aynchronous communcations channel is the transactional properties, allowing the infrastructure to retry failed jobs, group jobs together and such. Without knowing more about your specific setup, it is hard to give detailed advise.

Cheers,

Comment: Its not a database query. The program takes a very large file and produces a file from this Input.

Comment: I read that with spring batch, resource management could be used. This would be very helpfull because my applicatiin server isnt aware of the spawned external processes. Do you have any information on how this is managed in spring batch ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar design requirement, users were sending XML files and I had to generate documents from them. Using JMS in this case is advantageous since you can always add new instances of these processes which can consume and execute the jobs in parallel.

You can use a timer task to check status or monitor these processes. Also, you can publish a message to a JMS queue once the processes are completed.

Comment: But what happens if such a message bean isn't returning a result because the process which is computing the result is stuck. Isn't this the same problem which can occur with EJBs too? Did you have these problems in your application too?